# How to classify images which are slightly different from each other?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, classification, image-processing

*(I hope I'm in the right place to ask such a question.)*

A robot has a fixed camera which takes images before extending its sticks to grab a box from two sides and pull it back. But if the box is not in straight position and is rotated more than ~15% from its original straight position (a), robot's sticks cannot retrieve the box because the box will have extended its length (`h+α`) close to its diagonal length. I tried to visualize the case below:

[image]

Here, I want to collect hundreds of such images and classify them as `straight`, `rotated`, and if the image of rotated (either side) box is detected I should be able to send a notification to control unit to increase the robot's arms accordingly.

I couldn't think of any computer vision/image processing technique to address this issue, so
I wonder if a simple CNN can classify such small rotations.

What would be the optimal approach to this, in general?
Thanks.

Comment: To simplify your explanation - can we refer to this task as a binary classification given both regular and slanted images? Furthermore, have you tried some classical approaches like looking for edges and their angles w.r.t some fixed point?

Comment: @HadarSharvit yes, it could be thought as a binary classification task. I didn't try any classical approach, because if the box's longer edge isn't visible due to the occlusion of its near shorter edge (as in image b) the method would fail. Besides, although the camera is fixed into robot, the robot itself is supposed to move to various locations, and box may be in different shapes, so I tend to think that there is no one-fits-all solution in classical approaches.